# Spock "where" with dependent variables

Tags: groovy, spock

I am trying to do some data driven testing in Spock.

I have 1 variable which depends on an other one : ie

```
Services = ["tf1", "fr2"]
Questions(service) = ["What is on {service} ?", "Switch to {service}"]
```

I want my test to check all the possible combinations of Services and Questions(Service) : a total of 4 tests.

I tried writing a `where:` clause like that :

```
    where:
      service << SERVICES
      question << Questions(service)
```

But that fails at runtime with a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: service for class: com.my.testclass`

Has someone found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Here is what I do now, I find it hard to read so not so appropriate for tests : where:
        [service, question] << SERVICES
                .collectMany{s -> getQuestions(s)
                .collect{q -> [s, q]}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible, all variables must have the same cardinality. For each `service` entry there must be exactly one corresponding `question`.
What you wrote in your comment is the correct way to do it, you could extract it into a helper method `where: [service, question] << serviceQuestionsCombinations()`.